# type safe memory allocation with dart ffi

Tags: dart, generics, ffi, dart-ffi

I'm trying to make my code a little more robust when allocating memory for ffi.

I've written the following function:

```dart
void withMemory<T extends NativeType>(
    int size, void Function(Pointer<T> memory) action) {
  final memory = calloc<Int8>(size);
  try {
    action(memory.cast());
  } finally {
    calloc.free(memory);
  }
}
```

To call the above function I use:

```dart
withMemory<Uint32>(sizeOf<Uint32>(), (phToken) {
  // use the memory allocated to phToken
});
```

This works but as you can see I need to pass Uint32 twice as well as the `sizeOf`.

What I really want to write is:

```dart
withMemory<Uint32>((phToken) {
  // use the memory allocated to phToken
});
```

The problem is that you can't pass a generic type to either `calloc` or `sizeOf` without the error:

> The type arguments to [...] must be compile time constants but type
> parameters are not constants. Try changing the type argument to be a
> constant type.

Is there any way around this problem?

Comment: I guess the optimisations the Dart team wanted for FFI that @daco-harkes listed in https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/44621 meant the need to sacrifice being able to do sizeOf() or memory allocation for generics.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can now be done with the `Arena` allocator from `package:ffi`.

```dart
using((Arena arena) {
  final p = arena<Uint32>();
  // Use the memory allocated to `p`.
}
// Memory freed.
```

Documentation:

- https://pub.dev/documentation/ffi/latest/ffi/using.html
- https://pub.dev/documentation/ffi/latest/ffi/Arena-class.html

Comment: thanks for pointing that out! completely didn't realise that Arena was available or that it makes this kind of usage possible.

Comment: Nice one Daco! This is really useful.